# How to change numbers in columns?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a da|b' ,12, 14], [ 'e', 13, 15]]), columns=[['First', 'Second', 'Third']])

for elem in df_test.iloc[0:, 0]:
x = bool(re.search(r"\|", elem))
if x == True:
    x1 = re.split(r"\|", elem)
    for split_elem in x1:
        df_test.loc[len(df_test)] = split_elem
```

[image: Output of my code]

I need to change values of new separated elements to values of original one. For example: 'a da|b' was divided into "a da" and "b", so values in the "Second"column must be 12, in the "Third" column - 14. The same goes for new "b".

If it is needed, you can change the code of cycle I pinned.

Comment: `df_test.assign(First=df_test['First'].str.split('|')).explode('First')` (make sure to use a single level for your columns, not a MultiIndex with one level)